# How to call a PHP function with Ajax?

Tags: ajax

I have a PHP function which returns an array :

```
function lire( $id) {
            $ret = array() ; 
            $sSQL = "SELECT  *  FROM produit WHERE prod_code = '$id' LIMIT 1" ;
            $this->db->query($sSQL) ;
            $ret['cnt'] = $this->db->num_rows() ;
                        return $ret;
}
```

How can I call this PHP function within Ajax ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Ajax to call PHP function for HTML button Onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754571/use-ajax-to-call-php-function-for-html-button-onclick)

Comment: Actually that is not a good duplicate, but you find tons of similar questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+call+php+function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put this code block in a php file and will have to call it in the ajax function like:

```
    var value = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name="+customvariable,
    async: false
    }).responseText;
```

also the some.php file will have

```
      if(isset($_POST['name']))
       {
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $ret = array() ; 
        $sSQL = "SELECT  *  FROM produit WHERE prod_code = '$id' LIMIT 1" ;
        $this->db->query($sSQL) ;
        $ret['cnt'] = $this->db->num_rows() ;
                    echo $ret;
      }
```

You will get the return value in the **value** variable.

Comment: The code you gave seemed that the return value is got when I submit the form ! But what I want is to check the return value of the function in the onBlur of an input text so that if the return value is greater than 0 then I must show an alert ! How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

In AJAX you make simple HTTP request to some web resource. To get the data from your function you can provide simple php script which will have url parameter (id) and call your function. Than you

can use suitable Javascript libaray (e.g. jQuery) to call the page with that parameter.

```
function lire( $id) {
        $ret = array() ; 
        $sSQL = "SELECT  *  FROM produit WHERE prod_code = '$id' LIMIT 1" ;
        $this->db->query($sSQL) ;
        $ret['cnt'] = $this->db->num_rows() ;
                    return $ret;
}

$result = lire($_GET['id']); // CONSIDER SOME ESCAPING OF USER INPUT FOR SECURITY!
echo $result; // OR USE SOME OTHER SORT OF SERIALIZATION (e.g. JSON)
```

Maybe you will have to set the headers (MIME type of the result).

Answer (score 0):

this is the response to the comment you added earlier. I couldnt format it in the comment. Sorry.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#idofinput").blur(function(){


    var value = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name="+$("#idofinput").val(),
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    myval= parseInt(value);

    if(myval>0)
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
    else
    {
    //your code goes here
    }



    }); 

    });
```

You may attach the function with the input element on document load.

replace the **idofinput** with input element id

Comment: How to attach the function to the input text on document load ?

Comment: if u have included jquerry and you put the script in the head section then it will work for the input if you replace the  **idofinput** with the id of your input element.