# Running function on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run this function `set_downloads($file[0]);` when the download button is clicked, i can't just add it in the code, as it will run. I can put it on a different page and do some sort of onclick event to load it, but i don't know how to do this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = 0;
        var r = 0;
        function countdown() {
            if (x > 1) {
                x--;
                document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
                r = setTimeout("countdown()",0);
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(r);
                document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to download (<?php echo $filesize;?>) ";
                document.getElementById("button").disabled = "";
                document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementById("button").disabled = "disabled";

                    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Your download is starting..";

                };

            }
        }
        setTimeout("countdown()",1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label>
    <font size="5"></font>
</label>
<a href="http://IP/uploads/<?php echo $fullfile; ?>" >

    <button class="btn large orange" id="button" disabled="disabled">Click to download (<?php echo $filesize;?>) </button>

</a>
```

Comment: I have, how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 0;
    var r = 0;
    function countdown() {
        if (x > 1) {
            x--;
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
            r = setTimeout("countdown()",0);
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(r);
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to download (<?php echo $filesize;?>) ";
            document.getElementById("button").disabled = "";
            document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("button").disabled = "disabled";

                document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Your download is starting..";

            };

        }
    }
    setTimeout("countdown()",1000);

     $('.btn').click(function(){
        set_downloads($file[0]);
     });
});
```

This event handler is what you want to use to handle events.  It uses a callback, which calls that function argument after the button is clicked.

The other thing is, I'm not sure about your $file[0] variable, or where your set_downloads function is defined. where do you set these?

Comment: I've added this in and it doesn't seem to be working, where abouts would you put it in my code?

Comment: The set_downloads($file) is from a PHP function that is included into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but could you not just use a `$(document).ready(handler)` to ensure the DOM is loaded if needed then just use a onclick as you suggested:

`.click( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )`

eventDataA map of data that will be passed to the event handler.

handler(eventObject)A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

**EDIT:**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  set_downloads($file[0]);
});
```

Not sure if you would really need this inside a ready() but if so, you would just enclose the function for click() inside here:

```
$(document).ready( {

// Function for button goes here

});
```

**EDIT#2**

```
$(document).ready({ 
   $('.btn').click(
     {
       $.ajax({ url: 'script.php?argument=value&foo=bar' });
)};
```

));

You could place your php script inside a seperate file and call it using ajax and the url: then set any arguments if needed. I wouldnt copy and paste what I put considering I am mobile and its difficult to see brackets :/

You could also take a look here, A slightly different example still using Ajax and Jquery but may work slightly nicer for your desired application:

[Use Ajax to call PHP function for HTML button Onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754571/use-ajax-to-call-php-function-for-html-button-onclick)

Comment: Hope the example helps, it is basically the same as @Evan posted

Comment: something like this? <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( {
$('.btn').click(function(){
 <?php set_downloads($file[0]);?>;
});
});

</script>

Comment: Not exactly, I will Edit and show another option that may be easier for you.

Comment: If I were you, I would really take a deeper look into jquery and ajax, from a personal perspective it has changed my programming life tremendously over the past few weeks. I would say a solid 2 afternoons tinkering with it will go a long way =) http://jquery.com